# cbind and match in data.frame structure

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table, data-manipulation

As I am new to the [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) package, I would like to replicate what I would normally do in a [data.frame](/questions/tagged/data.frame) structure below, to a data.table structure.

```
Dta     <- data.frame(Customer = c("Javier","Oscar","Ivan","Peter"),Type_of_Customer=LETTERS[c(1,1:3)])
Dtb     <- data.frame(Customer = c("Javier","Oscar","Ivan","Jack"),Zone=5:8,District=100:103)
Result  <- cbind(Dtb[match(Dtb[,"Customer"],Dta[,"Customer"]),c("Zone","District")],Dta)


ww     <- which(is.na(Result[,"Zone"]))
if(length(ww) > 0){
  Result[ww,"Zone"] <- "Not in Dtb"
}

ww     <- which(is.na(Result[,"District"]))
if(length(ww) > 0){
  Result[ww,"District"] <- "Not in Dtb"
  }
```

So If I had `Dta` and `Dtb` as data.table structure, what would be the way to go?
(Note: In the real sample I have around 10 million rows so I would need the more time-efficient solution)

```
Dta     <- data.table(Custumer = c("Javier","Oscar","Ivan","Peter"),Type_of_Customer=LETTERS[c(1,1:3)])
Dtb     <- data.table(Custumer = c("Javier","Oscar","Ivan","Jack"),Zone=5:8,District=100:103)
```

Thanks.

Comment: The variable "Result" is what I expect as output.

Comment: I posted a solution, pllease check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use a join `on` thee 'Custumer' and replace the `NA` elements with 'Not in 'Dtb' string

```
Dtb[Dta, on = .(Custumer)][, c("Zone", "District") := 
    .(as.character(Zone), as.character(District))
     ][is.na(Zone), c("Zone", "District") := "Not in Dtb"][]
#    Custumer       Zone   District Type_of_Customer
#1:   Javier          5        100                A
#2:    Oscar          6        101                A
#3:     Ivan          7        102                B
#4:    Peter Not in Dtb Not in Dtb                C
```

Comment: That worked great,  Thank you so much!  Can you please recommend a preferable source of data.table tutorials or knowledge where I can learn from?

Comment: @MaxMolina you can check the vignettes of `data.table`